# Javascript generate random number from 0 to 75

Tags: javascript

I am using something like this:
`alert("Random number is: "+ Math.floor(Math.random() * 75) + 0);`.
To create a random number between 0 and 75. Any idea how I can create a random number between 0 and 75 that IS NOT one of the numbers in this comma-parsed string:
`$not_these_numbers = "17,26,52,75";`.

Comment: You can create an array of random numbers (0-75, excluding those numbers) then generate random index.

Comment: The random number will never be 75 since [Math.random](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.14) returns a number greater than or equal to zero and less than one. Use `* 76` or `* 75 + 1` (which are essentially the same thing).

Comment: Excuse me, I meant array of numbers 0 to 75.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate array of numbers (0-75, excluding those numbers) then generate random index:

```
var exclude = "17,26,52,75".split(',');
var numbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= 75; i++) {
    if (exclude.indexOf(i+'') == -1)
        numbers.push(i);
}

// will never be one of the numbers in exclude array
var random_number = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
```

Comment: I like the precomputed table idea. Reminds me of CRC generating code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object:

```
function getRandLimited() {
  var invalid = { 17:17, 26:26, 52:52, 75:75};
  var rand;
  do {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 76);
  } while (rand in invalid);
  return rand;
}
```

Comment: You could replace the object with an array and use the `indexOf` function.

Comment: Sure, but `Array.prototype.indexOf` is ES5, the above works more widely, and property access is likely (imperceptibly) faster than value lookup.